# What is this piece slightly longer than a 2x2 plate with grooves and a hole?

Tags: part-identification

Once again, I need the collective wisdom of this group to identify a mystery LEGO element!

I did a search for "2x2"and went through scores of Bricklink pages, but I couldn't find this particular piece.

It's the size of a 2x2 plate, but with this added grooved part that I've never seen before.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you find a number anywhere on the bottom of the brick? [I can just about make up something that looks like '90-7' but I'm not sure.](http://i.imgur.com/zVSFaBd.png)

Comment: @Ambo100 I think it's "4-06" upside down?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This looks like a [PLATE 2X2 ANGLE](https://brickset.com/parts/design-3956), which is broken. There is a rough side shown on the picture.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it was intentionally smoothed a bit after cutting or breaking, possibly for some one-off custom purpose.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: I have lots of parts that are 30-40 years old that have a broken edge that is now rounded because it was in use for so long

Comment: Huh, I thought it was familiar. Good job!

Comment: Sorry for the delay--there is indeed a Lego part number on the bottom, which is 3956. On closer inspection, I think the above comments are right--the broken edge is not completely flat, but rounded! No wonder I couldn't find this in Bricklink.  Thanks to all!